# What is the difference between Technic and Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack, minecraft-tekkit

I have found that Tekkit is the most amazing Minecraft mod ever, but I notice that often Technic is also listed with Tekkit. So, I must ask: What is Technic and how do I use it (is it a server mod, client mod, etc.)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say that the most major difference is the addition of the Thaumcraft and Mystcraft mods in Technic. As others have said, Tekkit is for use in a multiplayer setting, while Technic is for SSP only.

The major mods in both are IndustrialCraft2 (adds electricity and industrial machines), Equivalent Exchange 2 (adds in alchemy using the Philosopher's Stone, and several highly powerful end-game tools like the Void Ring, Ring of Arcana, etc), Redpower 2 (adds in redstone wiring and machines), and Buildcraft (adds in some automated mining machines as well as transport tubes and controls for that).

In addition to those core mods shared by both packs, Technic adds several features that are best in singleplayer. Major differences are:

- **Thaumcraft / Thaumcraft 2:** Thaumcraft is a magic and arcana inspired mod for Minecraft. It features aura and vis (pronounced "vees"), which introduces a new mechanic for enchanting and crafting unique items. Thaumcraft also introduces the "Taint" - if you've ever played Terraria, the Corruption from that game is similar to the Taint in Thaumcraft.
- **MystCraft:** MystCraft is a mod for Minecraft inspired by the *Myst* series of video games. It allows the player to craft different types of books which allow for teleportation between different "ages", which are basically new worlds. As you get more advanced, you can write your own books, which lets you customize the ages to your liking. For instance, I wrote an age with the "Hell" modifier, which spawned me in a world with a ton of Eldritch Obelisks (artifacts of great power in Thaumcraft), which helped me to get ahead on my research.

A few other minor changes worth mentioning:

- **Somnia:** Simulates the world while you're sleeping. So, unlike vanilla Minecraft, when you sleep, stuff smelts, crops grow, etc.
- **Mo' Creatures:** Basically what it says on the tin. There's a ton more creatures in Technic than there are in regular Minecraft.
- **Treecapitator:** Handy little mod so that, if you chop the bottom of a tree out with an ax, all the wood in the tree falls down at once (kind of like real life, eh?).

Comment: I'd say Mo' Creatures is a fairly major mod. It may not add many new mechanics, besides rideable creatures, but it causes quite a large change in the world.

Comment: +1, fair point. The world is much more animated thanks to Mo' Creatures.

Comment: Why the downvote? Was something wrong with this answer?

Comment: I find it worth mentioning that Redpower also adds microblocks, allowing you to create sub-meter structures like a glass table or slates above (wall-attached) wires. _Very_ neat for compact structures

Answer (score 10):

### Tekkit

Tekkit is for multiplayer.

Mods in Tekkit:

- Forge API
- IndustrialCraft 2
- Redpower 2
- Buildcraft
- Equivalent Exchange 2
- Railcraft
- ComputerCraft
- Balkons Weapon Mod
- Ender Storage
- Immibis Core/TubeStuff/Dimensional Anchors
- IronChests
- Nether Ores
- Wireless Redstone Chicken Bones Edition
- Not Enough Items (NEI)
- Power Converters
- MAtmos
- Rei's Minimap
- Inventory Tweaks

### Technic

Technic is for singleplayer only.

Mods in Technic **are as the ones above, plus**:

- Thermal Expansion
- Somnia
- Optifine
- GuiAPI
- ID Resolver
- Thaumcraft
- Mystcraft
- Treecapitator
- Steve's Carts
- Mo' Creatures

As you see there is a lot more mods in Technic.

Comment: Ah, there we go. The biggest thing I miss in Tekkit is Mo' Creatures

Comment: Is it possible to install Optifine into Tekkit too?

Comment: it is already in the modpack... if your somehow dont have it. Yes its possible but a bit strange to do :D

Answer (score 2):

While Tekkit is an SMP mod, Technic is SSP only. This means it cannot be played with others, but it allowed them to add quite a few mods which were not feasible in an SMP setting. I'd post a list of the mod differences, but the Technic site is blocked here, so I'll have to do so when I get home, unless someone feels like editing it in.

The easiest way to use Technic is to download the Technic launcher from their [website](http://www.technicpack.net/). This will give you a choice to run Tekkit, Technic, Hack/Mine, Yogbox, or Voxel Modpack.

Answer (score -1):

Tekkit is not illegal for one thing, and it's not just for mulitplayer. Tekkit has around 110 mods added, and you can launch it through the Technic Launcher Modpack. There are 3 versions, as of 2/27/15: Tekkit, Tekkit Lite, and Tekkit Classic. I prefer Tekkit, because it has Galacticraft wich allows you to go to the Moon, Mars, and create your own space station. Other mods include AE(Applied Energistics) which adds a computer to the game that you can upgrade, and create recipes for that allow you to tell it to craft things. It's like a HUGE chest in a few blocks. The more hard drives you add, the more space you have. Then you have Buildcraft which adds a Quarry(Mines for you), Pumps(Is a pump), and pipes, and oil. Thermal Expansion adds a way to double your ores through pulverizing and smelting. Tekkit also adds Nether Ores. Nether Ores have a ton more stuff inside a single block. Most people don't know but if you pulverize Redstone Nether ore, it gives you 24 Redstone. To me, it's worth to get nether ores. Plus, it adds TONS of stuff that uses Redstone. But the mod is based off of one thing...THE RACE TO THE MOON!And for one thing. It does NOT have any magical mods.

Comment: It's a little messy your answer, could you improve the format by adding line-breaks, markdown and stuff like that. (like a list of cons and a list of pros for each one)

Comment: Are you implying that Technic is illegal? Do you have a source of that?