# Horrible Lag in Technic/Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-technic-pack

### Overview

So, [I'm playing Tekkit and Technic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85834/what-is-the-difference-between-technic-and-tekkit), and it seems like there is horrible lag. The lag is so terrible that I died trying to kill a wolf on Peaceful. I have an average of 2-3 fps for the first ~5 minutes. Once the chunks are all loaded and ready to go, I have an average of 7-13 frames per second. This is very little, considering that in normal vanilla, I average 30-50 fps.

### What I have already done

I have already removed two mods, I believe one of them was Mo'Creatures and the other one was MatAmos (or whatever that is). This has increased it from unplayable to a maximum of 17 fps. These two were one of the mods that does heavy calculation, but I often am killed by a creeper or a zombie when I fluctuate from 0 to 3 fps. I have additionally turned everything in OptiFine off and have changed my render distance to Short +16.

### Question

How can I reduce lag in Tekkit/Technic? Is it possible to remove some mods that I care less about, or is there an easier solution?

**System Specs**
[image: System Specs, also listed below]
Sony Vaio running Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) 
6 Gigabytes of RAM, 3 given to the Technic Launcher
Intel Core i5 processor
Nvidia GPU (not sure what specs)
Java version 1.7.0_05 (32-bit since for some reason, x64 doesn't like me)

Comment: switch to [feed the beast](http://www.feed-the-beast.com)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: As I understand it, the most CPU-intensive mod in tekkit is BuildCraft, which is also included in that mod pack.  Unfortunately, it's also the most awesome - Tekkit without quarries just wouldn't be Tekkit anymore, so simply disabling BuildCraft would ruin it.

Comment: @Jeff:  I've heard of some people having issues in Single Player but not on multiplayer *(since then the server is doing most of the CPU-intensive work)*.  Have you tried playing on a multiplayer server and just moving far, far away from spawn *(so you don't get griefed)*?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yeah but in the FTBLauncher you can disable specific mods

Comment: @Jeffrey-lin What are your system specs?

Comment: If you could get the specs on you NVIDIA, it will probably help.  Windows 7 x64 or x32?  My desktop is an i5-2500k with 8GB of RAM and an NVidia GeForce GTX 560 Ti, and Technic runs pretty smoothly (though it does make my fans ramp up something fierce).  Since you're running on a laptop it'd help to have your GPU specs since I suspect that might be the bottleneck.  I'm also wondering if overheat is an issue.

Comment: @TARehman My computer isn't overheating, but it did [recently break down](http://superuser.com/questions/513759/windows-wont-boot-gives-blue-screen/513769) and I am currently sending it back to Sony for repairs. Meanwhile, I am using a HP MobileWorkstation with 4GB, barely enough to run Technic without it throttling the CPU.

Comment: Hmm, well, your Vaio should be able to run Technic pretty well I would think; looking at the specs, it sounds similar to my desktop (though 2 cores instead of 4). It might be worth seeing if Java is using both of the cores (Task Manager, Set Affinity).

Comment: Also make sure that it's not running an integrate GPU instead of the NVidia GPU.

Comment: The other answer helped. Unfortunately, I [can't play Technic anymore](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104115/technic-launcher-broken-in-windows-8?rq=1), so now I'm playing FTB, as per @ratchetfreak 's suggestion.

Comment: Related:  [Extreme Block Lag on Minecraft Feed The Beast](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112808)

Comment: 30-50 fps in vanilla isn't very good at all. I got about that much, and my computer also gets 2-3 fps routinely on full tekkit. I switched to tekkit lite, getting more like 20 fps, it's bearable. The fps you're getting isn't surprising at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are playing with a pack that includes ExtrabiomesXL, stay away from the redwood forests. The leaves of the redwood trees extend further from the trunk than vanilla Minecraft allows, meaning that upon entering the biome, hundreds of redwood sapling entities are created and dropped. While these can be great for early fuel, rendering all them absolutely kills your FPS.

Perhaps this is what caused your 2-3 FPS while killing (or being killed by) the wolf?

Answer (score 2):

If anything, try disabling Matmos (no idea why it would lag, just that it's the only thing that's constantly running in the background), Smart Moving (again, no idea why it would lag, but I know it's running in the background), and potentially even Optifine. You could be running an Optifine build that isn't meant for your hardware which could cause the lagging. In my opinion, that's the most likely- even though by default Technic ships with Optifine Standard which is unlikely to cause that kind of effect.

Don't remove too many mods, especially from Tekkit- then you can't join any servers! And if you remove mods from Technic, maps you download from online may not function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things your CPU isn't enough to handle tekkit. Mine has a turbo boost of 3.10 GHz, even with that I lag. If anything, turn your render distance to tiny but turn fog off. If you want to remove mods (this may ruin tekkit) get rid of the one that creates volcanoes and oil, more map generations are going to make your CPU work a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Tekkit or Technic on Windows, set the priority to high in Task Manager. You will not be able to use other applications without lag, but at least Minecraft should work. I am not sure how to do this in a Mac, but if you can find the process, then try to change it so that it is the highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run any custom texture packs? I had the same issue attempting to run 256x Sphax BDCraft, Didn't matter what settings i ran Minecraft at; the framerate was somewhere between 0 and... well, 1.

Switch back to the default texture if you're using a custom one and see if there's an improvement. Then try installing a lower resolution one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should remove any additional mods that are not in the tekkit pack and switch to the default minecraft textures .this may ruin playing experience  but a t least you still have tekkit.