# Technic Launcher broken in Windows 8

Tags: minecraft-technic-pack

My Technic Lanucher does not start. It just has the screen that says "Technic Launcher". There is no .techniclauncher folder created, and I have to kill the process with task manager. There are no Windows 8 graphic drivers for my computer and I am using the latest version of Java. Why is this happening?

EDIT: I am using the graphic drivers that came with Windows. However, as Notch stated, these drivers are not optimal for gaming and stuff like that.

Comment: Are you running it as Administrator?

Comment: @fbueckert I am using the .jar file, even though I am on Windows. Both don't work either way.

Comment: The .jar file just uses Java to run itself; if this is a UAC issue, pretty sure you still need to run it as Administrator.  As a test, you could try disabling UAC entirely, and see what it does.

Comment: What do you mean, "There are no Windows 8 graphic drivers for my computer"? What drivers are you using then?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The default ones that came with Windows.

Comment: @fbueckert just tried it, nothing happened

Comment: Ok, not UAC.  Wierd.

Comment: Does vanilla minecraft run? And can you post the launcher's log? It may have useful info.

Comment: Vanilla Minecraft runs, but usually crashes and gives a nullpointerexception when I die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various searches indicate that many people have problems with Technic Launcher using default Windows 8 video drivers. There is currently no fix. Either downgrade to Windows 7 or (assuming vanilla Minecraft runs at all) look into converting your map for FTB or another modpack that includes the same mods, but with a launcher that doesn't have these issues.

Comment: FTB also randomly crashes, without an error log.

Comment: Then downgrading to Windows 7 is the remaining option that doesn't involve installing all those mods manually. Or waiting until there are native graphics drivers that work with 8.

Answer (score 0):

Dont want to see all this typing? Skip to the ***Bold and Italic Writing!***

I know, that this comment is WAY WAY Late, but for others who may be having the problem like me (well i found a fix a few mins ago) and decide to come here for help; so the way i fixed it was by checking the log and finding out that it says something along the lines..."Feature no longer supported in 8" which means Java Version 8, and windows 8+ comes with java 8 (i think it does) so go ahead and ***Download Java Version 7 on the website, by any chance if your seeing this past April 2015, than the Java 7 is taken down!***

Comment: You know this was asked last year right?