# What do I do in Technic/Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-technic-pack

As you may have noticed, I have always had a [fascination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85834/what-is-the-difference-between-technic-and-tekkit) with Technic and Tekkit. I started reading up on it, but got lost very fast since there are many mods to read up on, and many things to cross-reference and so on. Therefore, I have to ask: *is there a tutorial for technic/tekkit or like some kind of beginners' guide?*

Comment: Hope this is more of what you were looking for, sorry I didnt add this in the beginning didn't realize you wanted the extra fluff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, mods like this would be near impossible to use without some sort of guide.

For starters here is a **Youtube channel** that has some pretty good videos all about the mod.

[Technical Minecraft At Its Best W/ Odedex](http://www.youtube.com/user/odedex)

In Odedex's Technical Minecraft playlist he starts of with a brand new game using the mod. He touches everything in the mod in a fun to watch series in an easy to understand pace.

If that doesn't do it for you here is a **Wiki page** all about getting started with *Tekkit/Technic*

[Wiki Starting Guide](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Started)

The **Getting Started** wiki guide does a really good job helping you get started with incredibly important aspects of the mod such as:

- New Ores to mine for like [Copper](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Copper) and [tin](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Tin), which will be the foundation of a large quantity of the new recipes.
- An important tree to locate, known as the [Rubber Tree](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Rubber_Tree_(IndustrialCraft)) and how to gather [Rubber](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Rubber) from it.
- Basics of making Electricity w/ [Generators](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Generator) and [Batteries](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/RE_Battery), which will help you get started in making more advanced machinery.
- Some of the Basic Machines, like the [Extractor](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Extractor) that allows you to double the output of certain items like [Sticky Resin](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Sticky_Resin) and the [Macerator](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Macerator), which will increase the output of the ores you mine by double.
- Very importantly is how it touches renewable natural energy from [Windmills](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Mill) and [Solar Panels](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Panel) so you can use all your machines without burning through gathered resources.

*Also here is a Wiki page that has a link to every guide available on the Wiki*.

[Tutorials](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Tutorials)

I'd like to point out a couple of them like:

[Engine Cooling](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial/Engine_Cooling)

[Diamond Maker](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial/Diamond_Maker)

This Mod is so vast and amazing, you'll never wanna go back to Vanilla. I recommend this to every avid Minecraft player as its a whole new game to anyone who enjoys Minecraft as much as I have.

Comment: It would be nice if you state what is in the links in case the website ever goes down, but this is good too. Thanks!

Comment: Ill add more no worries

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started playing Tekkit.

I figure starting off with your average vanilla Minecraft helps a lot but as soon as you get to mining these awkward ores it gets pretty tricky but what I do is make sure I have NEI (not enough items) on and as soon as I get an ore I search it up in there but it can always helps to make a creative world first just to see what everything does.